# can I add a tag to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment while using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I found tags are not fully supported in aws, for example, when launch an environment in aws console, i can specify the tag, but I can't find a way to specify the tag use cloudformation. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add tags to the resources that you create using CloudFormation.
Here is how you can add tags to the instances that you create:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-tagging.html